# Cache user control

Tags: asp.net

The problem of ouputcaching is avoiding accessing the object, it is cached and it will not be processed at **ALL** and it is a HTML. for example, what if I want to post back to initialize countries drop down list with specific selection, I don't want to go back and rebuild the whole control and rebind to a collection of countries to just intialize the contol to a certain country.

Output caching will not solve the problem because it caches the HTML, not the object, the object will be null, I can't manipulate it.

Is there away to cache the **server object** rather than caching its **output html**?

If u don't think this is possible please reply back, so I know that it is impossible if alot of people say so.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite possible - just use the [**HttpRuntime cache**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx):

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("myKey", myCountryList);
```

And then fetch the object back out:

```
CountryList myCountryList = HttpRuntime.Cache["myKey"] as CountryList;
if(myCountryList == null)
{
    //the object isn't in cache
}
```

This is the most simple usage - the cache is fairly robust and supports some more complex behaviors like invalidation, callbacks, etc. which is all covered in the link above.